# Сравнить значения двух массивов с помощью IComparable C#

Tags: c#

Нужно сравнить два интовых массива с помощью интерфейса IComparable. Как реализировать метод, что сравнивает у каждого массива Length и выведет -1, если  первый массив меньше за второй, 0, если они равны, и 1, если первый больше второго? Прочитал миллион ресурсов, но так и не нашел ответ на свой вопрос.

```
class Numbers :IComparable
{
    private int[] arr;
    public int[] Arr { get; set; }
    public Numbers(int[] arr)
    {
        this.Arr = arr;
    }
    public void arr_rand(int[] arr)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = rand.Next(-100, 101);
            Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    public int Sum_Arr(int[] arr)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<arr.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += arr[i];

        }
        return sum;
    }
    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        Numbers temp = (Numbers)obj;
        if (Arr > temp.Arr) return 1;
        if (Arr == temp.Arr) return 0;
        if (Arr < temp.Arr) return -1;

    }

}
```

`

Comment: Что значит "один массив меньше второго"?

Comment: зависит от количества элементов массива

Comment: Ваше имя "Равшан"? *"Подоконник должен быть вровень со стеной или немного выступать?"*

Comment: @Igor думаю это было несколько грубо. Не все могут ясно выражать свои мысли. Этому нужно учится и со временем это начнет получаться. Уверен, что у каждого была подобная проблема. Без исключений.

Comment: А разве https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_SequenceEqual__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__ не решает эту же задачу?